# how to solve Firebase CLI error on start up

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli

when I open firebase CLI I get this error :

```
 Let's make sure your Firebase CLI is ready...
undefined:1



SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\snapshot\firepit\welcome.js:115:27)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1021:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (internal/child_process.js:443:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at Pipe.<anonymous> (net.js:668:12)
```

[image]

I am using windows 10 pro

Comment: If you have a bug to report, post that in the Firebase CLI github.  https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools

Comment: I am not sure if it's a bug. it's my first time to use firebase CLI

Comment: I got the same error. Copying firebase-tools-instant-win.exe to any folder on drive C: worked but not on any other drive. No ideea why.

Comment: This happens for me when I run it directly from the Downloads directory on C: drive.

Answer (score 26):

The comment on the original question was the solution for me. My "Downloads" folder is hosted on D: and the installer assumes C:

([how to solve Firebase CLI error on start up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61923704/how-to-solve-firebase-cli-error-on-start-up#comment113734782_61923704))

Comment: Exactly, I just moved firebase_cli to C drive and it worked :)

Answer (score 17):

A solution that helped me after transferring the exe to C has failed, is deleting the folder:

```
C:\Users\{YOUR_PROFILE_NAME}\.cache\firebase
```

Hope this helps anyone

Comment: indeed it helped, thank you :)

Comment: It didn't help me :(

Comment: I deleted the firebase folder but this same error is coming

Comment: A corrupt install of Firebase CLI was uninstalled through this. I had downloaded the binary of firebase tools to begin with but my computer shut down before it could finish due to a bluescreenofdeath. BTW the corruption caused the `same error msg as in this question`!

Answer (score 12):

That is nothing to worry about, it only appears because the CLI by default assumes it is in the C directory.

So, copying the CLI exe to any other directory would show this message but, **you can still use all the CLI functionalities as you wish**.

Like what I did here using `firebase init`

[image: Firebase CLI]

Answer (score 8):

---

### The solution :

---

leave the exe name as: `"firebase-win.exe"` and you can move it to whatever folder you want

---

### The detailed explanation:

---

i moved the executable i downloaded (`"firebase-tools-instant-win.exe"`) to folder: `c:\firebase\bin`
and it works without any error,

but for some reason if i rename the exe file to something like: `"firebase.exe"` or `"fbcli.exe"` it will throw the json error and will not download the `.cache` folder correctly

but if i rename the exe name to: `"firebase-win.exe"` it works no matter what folder i put it in,

when checking C:\Users{YOUR_PROFILE_NAME}.cache\firebase\runtime\shell.bat

if the exe name is: `"firebase.exe"` (**Not working**) then the content is:

```
@echo off
"C:\firebase\bin\firebase.exe"  C:\Users\{YOUR_PROFILE_NAME}\CACHE~1\firebase\runtime\shell.js %*
```

if the exe name is: `"firebase-win.exe"` (**working**) then the content is:

```
@echo off
"C:\firebase\bin\FIREBA~1.EXE"  C:\Users\shaybc\.cache\firebase\runtime\shell.js %*
```

so i simply left the exe name: `"firebase-win.exe"`

**valid names worked for me:**

1. fireb-win.exe
2. firebase-win.exe
3. firebase-w.exe
4. fire-base.exe
5. fbcli-win.exe
6. ...

Comment: Strange! But it worked.

Answer (score 1):

leave the exe name as: "firebase-win.exe" and you can move it to whatever folder you want worked for me when in C drive

Answer (score 1):

copy firebase-tools-instant-win to c: drive and execute

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Install Firebase using npm:

`npm install firebase`

source:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

Comment: You are assuming the original question had access to node, which may not have been the case.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error. What helped me is to rename it back to the original name :firebase-tools-instant-win.exe. Previously I renamed it to firebase.exe, it seems that this caused the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me when i downloaded `firebase-tools-win.exe` instead of `firebase-tools-instant-win.exe` from https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/releases even after renaming it.

Answer (score -2):

I got this warning as well, but when I tried to init, serve, and deploy, it worked just fine. Good luck!

Comment: Hi, try posting this as a comment instead of an answer. If you want to answer the question, provide more substance.